# Format a date and time with fractional seconds in C++

Tags: c++, datetime, strftime

I want to format a date and time as a string using the format:

```
20130630-03:11:45.862
```

I can do most of this by using [strftime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/), however there is no clear way to achieve fractional seconds on the end.

My current code is:

```
time_t rawtime;
time(&rawtime);
tm* timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
char buffer[80];
strftime(buffer, 80, "%G%m%d-%I:%M:%S", timeinfo);
```

This produces the value without the fractional seconds part.

However ultimately I just want to have a string version of the date in this format, and don't care what API it takes.

I'm using g++ on Linux in case it's relevant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get higher precision (fractions of a second) in a printout of current time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15845505/how-to-get-higher-precision-fractions-of-a-second-in-a-printout-of-current-tim)

Comment: Maybe, but that answer doesn't quite solve Drew's problem.

Comment: Drew - the functions you're using only have a resolution of 1 second.  You need library functions that have greater resolution.

Comment: Well, if the question is "how do I do it with strftime" then answer is "you can't."  But he stated that he doesn't care what API it takes.  So I assume that STL is acceptable. Which menas, the answer I linked probably is sufficient to solve his issue.  @DrewNoakes, please advise.

Comment: yep, appears strftime is second granularity only <sigh>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the API, you could use [boost::date_time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/date_time.html) and it's [time_facet](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_time.time_facet).

Short example so far:

```
// setup facet and zone
// this facet should result like your desired format
std::string facet="%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%s";
std::string zone="UTC+00";

// create a facet
boost::local_time::local_time_facet *time_facet;
time_facet = new boost::local_time::local_time_facet;

// create a stream and imbue the facet
std::stringstream stream(std::stringstream::in | std::stringstream::out);
stream.imbue(std::locale(stream.getloc(), time_facet));

// create zone
boost::local_time::time_zone_ptr time_zone;
time_zone.reset(new boost::local_time::posix_time_zone(zone));

// write local from calculated zone in the given facet to stream
stream << boost::local_time::local_microsec_clock::local_time(time_zone);

// now you can get the string from stream
std::string my_time = stream.str();
```

This example is maybe incomplete, because I copied some code out of mine, but I hope you got the point.

With the facet, you can setup your format. The `%s` (small s with, big S without fractial) setup seconds with fractial. You can read this in the documentation [facet format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_time.format_flags).

The timezone is for calculating your local machine time to the right zone.